# Ajax function to fill table with images but cannot select with live

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table with a header and an empty body:

```
<table style="width:50%;" class="adminlist">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="width:80%;">Number</th>
<th style="width:20%;">Quantity</th>
<th style="width:20%;"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="body_orderproducts">
<tr style="background-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);">                      <td class="kmx_nodata" colspan="3">NO DATA.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I load the data and fill the tbody with an ajax function:

```
var baseurl = '<?php echo HtmlHelper::getComponentPath(true); ?>';
var urlquery_ajax = '<?php echo RouteHelper::urlQueryWithRawAndToken('order&task=');?>';
var order_id = <?php echo $this->item->id;?>;
var kmx = jQuery.noConflict();
kmx().ready(function() {
/**
* Ajax call to load the products linked to the order
*/
function loadTableProducts() {
    var myProductTableBody = kmx('#body_orderproducts');
    myProductTableBody.empty();
    kmx.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseurl,
        cache: false,
        data: urlquery_ajax + "getOrderProductsInJsonFormatAjax&order_id=" + order_id,
        success: function(data){
                    data = kmx.parseJSON(data);
                    var myProductTableBody = kmx('#body_orderproducts');
                    populateTable(myProductTableBody, data);
                 },
         failure: function(msg){
                    msg = kmx.trim(msg);
                    alert('Error: ' + msg.responseText);
                  }
    });
}
/**
* Populate the table
*/
function populateTable(myTBodyObj, myData) {
    if (myData.rows.length > 1) {
        kmx.each(myData.rows, function(index,item) {
            myTBodyObj.append('<tr><td>' + item.number + '</td><td align="right">' + item.quantity + '</td><td><img id="delete_product_' + item.id + '" name="delete_product_' + item.id + '" class="kmx_image_delete" alt="<?php echo JText::_( 'Delete this product'); ?>" src="components/com_cmpningbo/assets/images/delete.png" /></td></tr>');
        });
    }
    else {
        myTBodyObj.append('<tr><td colspan="2" class="kmx_nodata"><?php echo JText::_( 'NO DATA.'); ?></td></tr>');
    }
    return;
}}
loadTableProducts();
});
```

Everything works fine and the result is something like:
[image: Table body loaded successfully]

Now, I want to add a code to handle the event on click on the image "delete":

```
kmx('img[name^="delete_product_"]').live('click', function() {
        alert('click');
        return false;
    });
```

Each "delete" image has an id and name like: delete_product_XX, where XX is the ID of the record to delete.
That code doesn't work when the table body is loaded in ajax but it works when the table body is loaded on the page loading (no ajax).
I already checked about this problem and it seems that there is a problem with live about the images? I don't know how to solve that? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have a common class on all the delete buttons, you can just create a delegated event handler like this to handle them all with one event handler:

```
kmx("#body_orderproducts").on('click', '.kmx_image_delete', function() {
    // you can examine the other cells in this row to get the desired ID
    // or you can parse it off the end of the image id
    var deleteID = this.id.replace("delete_product_", "");
    // now do whatever you want to do to process the deleteID
});
```

To make the delegated event handling work for dynamically created objects, you set the first selector to a static parent object that is not dynamically created (that exists at the time you run the code to installed the event handlers) and you set the second selector to something that matches the dynamically create object.

FYI, `.live()` has been deprecated from all versions of jQuery.  For jQuery 1.7+, `.on()` is recommended.  For jQuery before 1.7, `.delegate()` is recommended.  This is because both `.delegate()` and `.on()` can be much more efficient than `.live()`.

For versions of jQuery before 1.7, it would be this:

```
kmx("#body_orderproducts").delegate('.kmx_image_delete', 'click', function() {
    // you can examine the other cells in this row to get the desired ID
    // or you can parse it off the end of the image id
    var deleteID = this.id.replace("delete_product_", "");
    // now do whatever you want to do to process the deleteID
});
```

Comment: I use JQuery 1.4.2 and your code produces the error: $("#body_orderproducts").on is not a function... This function is only available from 1.7...snif!

Comment: @YoongKim - Then, as my answer says, you need to use `.delegate()` because 1.4.2 doesn't have `.on()`.   See [the doc](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for `.delegate()` for the parameter order.  It works the same as `.on()` - with parameters in a different order.  In the future, if you're posting a question and are using an old version of jQuery, you should specify that in the question because people will nearly always answer with an answer based on the latest jQuery capabilities.

Comment: +1 It's always a good idea to use the latest version of a library, unless you have a very good reason for not upgrading. Browser vendors continue to push out updates to their platforms, and the jQuery team makes periodic releases to keep up with the changes.

Comment: @YoongKim - I added a version to my answer for older versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind all of our delete images using a single class selector, you can then use the "this" keyword to climb the DOM tree to your top level `tr` row element, then dig back down to grab the items you're interested in for your delete operation.

```
kmx('img.kmx_image_delete').live('click', function() {
    alert('click');
    alert("deleting row with id = " + kmx(this).parent().parent().find("td:first").html());
    return false;
});
```

This should also be much simpler to run since the live function will only have to look for all new rows added to the DOM that match that CSS class selector.

Using this code, if I click on the 2nd delete image in your list, I should see two alerts:

```
click

12
```

As a final note, the [jQuery live documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has made it clear that live is deprecated. It is superseded by the "on" method:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

The [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handler usage is very similar to live:

```
kmx('img.kmx_image_delete').on('click', function() {
    alert('click');
    alert("deleting row with id = " + kmx(this).parent().parent().find("td:first").html());
    return false;
});
```

If you continue having trouble with live failing to attach events to your delete image, I strongly recommend you upgrade to the latest version of jQuery and try using "on".

Comment: thank you for the suggest. My delete images have already a single class, "kmx_image_delete". Actually, I already tried this selector but it doesn't alert any message...

Comment: Then please look into my second part of the answer. As of jQuery 1.7, live is deprecated. I've experienced some buggy behavior with it myself. My suggestion is either use on, (or delegate maybe), or in the worst case, bind the event after loading the elements. The latter solution, binding the event after adding the image, is only something I would use as a last resort or just temporarily to meet your goal until you figure out how to use on or delegate.

Comment: yes your suggestion is the good one...but I need to wait a couple of hours to post the solution for other people...

Comment: If one of the answers listed answers your question, then you should consider accepting one. However, if they didn't solve the problem and you instead had to do something else, then it would be appropriate for you to post *your* solution. The idea of making you wait before answering your own question is to give the community time to answer your question and possibly get rewarded/acknowledged; otherwise, the system would get abused.

Answer (score 0):

ok, the method mentionned by jfriend00 works fine:

```
$kmx("#body_orderproducts").delegate('.kmx_image_delete', 'click', function() {
        var order_product_id = kmx(this).attr('id');
        order_product_id = order_product_id.replace('delete_order_product_', '');
        deleteProduct(order_product_id);
    });
```

But I don't know why the live method works in another parts of my application:

```
$('[class^="' + messageid_prefix + '"]').live('click', function() {
 var className = kmx(this).attr('className');
 var id = className.replace(messageid_prefix, '');
 [...]
});
```

JQuery 1.4